# Delete record in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image]
[image]

```
$qry=mysql_query("Select useradmin from tbladmin");
$credentials=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
header("location:index.php");
exit();
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){ 
mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblru WHERE userid=" . $_REQUEST['id']);
if(mysql_affected_rows($con)>0){
header("location:administration.php");
exit();
}
else{
echo "ERROR in deleting the user!";
}
}
?>
```

this upper part is placed on top. and the lower part is in the body.
    
    
    
    UserID
    Username
    Password
    Add Users

```
<?php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblru");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){      
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr bgcolor='#999999'>
<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>
<td>" . $row[1] . " </td>
<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>
<td><a href='admininistration.php?id=$row[0]' onClick=\"return confirm('Confirm Deletion of Registered User?');\"><font color='#FFFFFF'>Delete</font></a></td></tr>";
}
}
?>
```

I cant delete the users data in the database i made. the tblru has id(this is int and is auto incremented, user, and password. i would like to ask if the deletion of data is possible.

Comment: Are you getting id correct in `$_REQUEST` variable ?

Comment: if you learn from a tutorial get a new one. Dont ever eat userinput raw ($_GET, $_REQUEST etc...), use mysqli instead of mysql or even better PDO

Comment: @Soundz it doesn't matter if you use mysqli or PDO. But using prepared statements ;)

Comment: the suggestion to change to either PDO or mysqli wasnt related to the userinput comment. Oh and btw table designes are deprecated.

Comment: `?id=userid` and say bye !

Comment: Can you echo this .. 
echo "DELETE FROM tblru WHERE userid=" . $_REQUEST['id'];

Comment: You're storing passwords in plaintext and not hashing them? :(

Comment: @Wrikken can you please check this one

Comment: reffer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655540/delete-record-in-database-php/21655657#21655657

Answer (score 2):

Your link on your code:

```
"</td><td><a href='admininistration.php?id=$row[0]'
```

Notice how you just include an array variable inside of a string? That should be...

```
"</td><td><a href='admininistration.php?id=".$row[0]."'
```

Use a proper string concatenation.

That's the reason you're not getting the right/proper value that you need.

You're getting $row[0] as the value, literally. Check your url to see.

Comment: Another possible solution would be `"</td><td><a href='administration.php?id={$row[0]}'"`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an administration.php file? Is all this code in it?The errors says that the page does not exist.

This prints out just fine, it has " " not ' ' so it is seen as variable, just tested it.

```
$row[0] = rand(1,10);
$row[1] = rand(1,10);
$row[2] = rand(1,10);
echo "<tr bgcolor='#999999'>
<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>
<td>" . $row[1] . " </td>
<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>
<td><a href='admininistration.php?id=$row[0]' onClick=\"return confirm('Confirm Deletion of Registered User?');\"><font color='#FFFFFF'>Delete</font></a></td></tr>";
```

Are you sure you are passing by this part?

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}
```

if you are not, you will be redirected to  index.php and the rest of the script isn't going to run.

set $_SESSIONp['user'] = "something"; just before that just for test, are you getting the "ERROR in deleting the user!" when trying to delete?

Also separate the logical part from the display. and use md5() or sha1() for password encryption.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblru");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{      
    $output = "<table>"; 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output .= "<tr bgcolor='#999999'>";
        $output .= "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
        $output .= "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        $output .= "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        $output .= "<td><a href='admininistration.php?id=$row[0]' onClick=\"return confirm('Confirm      Deletion of Registered User?');\"><font color='#FFFFFF'>Delete</font></a></td></tr>";
        }
        $output .= "/table";
}

print_r $output;
```

Comment: i can pass this code if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}