# delete record in database-php

Tags: php, sql, database

I got this code in my administration.php:

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
header("location:index.php");
exit();
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['user'])){   
mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblru WHERE user=" . $_REQUEST['user']);
if(mysql_affected_rows($con)>0){
header("location:administration.php");
exit();
}
else{
echo "ERROR in deleting the user!";
}
}
?>
```

I got this code on the body:

```
<?php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblru");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{       
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr bgcolor='#999999'>
<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>
<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>
<td align='center'><a href='administration.php?user=" . $row[0]."' onClick=\"return confirm('Confirm Deletion of Registered User?');\"><font color='#FFFFFF'>Delete</font></a></td></tr>";

    }
}

?>
```

i keep getting error in deleteing records, can anyone check this out why it always displays like that

Comment: can you write error description here??

Comment: ERROR in deleting the user!

Comment: When you click on delete and it goes to `administration.php`, what's the URL you see in the address bar?

Comment: `var_dump($_REQUEST['user']);`

Comment: http://localhost/wdev/administration.php?user=johnmichael i get this url

Comment: Plus I don't know why you're using sessions, there's nothing assigned to one.

Comment: `mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblru WHERE user='" . $_REQUEST['user'] . "'");`

Comment: replace this ... mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblru WHERE user= ' " . $_REQUEST['user'] . " ' ");

Comment: And you really shouldn't be using your code in the state it's in. [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) is imminent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this below....

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
header("location:index.php");
exit();
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['user'])){
mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblru WHERE user= '" . $_REQUEST['user'] . "'");
if(mysql_affected_rows($con)>0){
header("location:administration.php");
exit();
}
else{
echo "ERROR in deleting the user!";
}
}
?>
```

if you want to use secure code that can not disturb from user then use below( SQL INJECTION)

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['user'])){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblru WHERE user= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['user']) . "'");
    if(mysql_affected_rows($con)>0){
    header("location:administration.php");
    exit();
    }
    else{
    echo "ERROR in deleting the user!";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/

Answer (score 1):

It also seems that you query isnt correct.

instead of

```
"DELETE FROM tblru WHERE user=" . $_REQUEST['user']
```

you should write

```
"DELETE FROM tblru WHERE user='" . $_REQUEST['user'] . "'"
```

because user is a varchar/string and not a number (that is my guess).

If you could post some kind of error (DB/Code?), then we would also know where to search.

Answer (score 0):

You shall connect to database first.
Use mysqli rather than mysql. It is a better approach.
Look at the example on http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php or on https://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect.

Good luck.